# Can't connect to https on ubuntu - "Unknown SSL protocol error"

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssl, https, openssl

I can't seem to connect to a specific server over SSL from our Ubuntu servers. Locally, on my Mac, it works flawlessly.

The server address:  powerschool.spokaneschools.org

**`curl -v https://powerschool.spokaneschools.org` output:**

> - Rebuilt URL to: https://powerschool.spokaneschools.org/
> - Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
> - Trying 206.193.1.72...
> - Connected to powerschool.spokaneschools.org (206.193.1.72) port 443 (#0)
> - successfully set certificate verify locations:
> - CAfile: none   CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
> - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
> - Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to powerschool.spokaneschools.org:443
> - Closing connection 0 curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to powerschool.spokaneschools.org:443

**`openssl s_client -connect powerschool.spokaneschools.org:443` output:**

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : SSLv3
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1466726411
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

I tried checking the site in different SSL check tools, all seem to be OK (apart from some security issues). I have no issues connecting to other servers, even within that domain.

**OS**

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

$ curl -V
curl 7.35.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.35.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP 

$ openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
built on: Mon May  2 16:53:18 UTC 2016
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: cc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -DMD32_REG_T=int -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
```

Comment: Works fine for me.  Either try using the "-k" option on curl, or please provide distro version and curl version ("curl -V") so we can understand the issue better.

Comment: @jehad added more info, adding `-k` had no effect. Did you manage to run it on ubuntu?

Comment: I'm using the exact same version of software as you (ubuntu server 14.04.4, running curl 7.35.0, openssl 1.0.1f), and I've also tried on my personal desktop machine running LinuxMint 17.3 (which also has the same curl/openssl components).  My ubuntu server is running in a virtualbox VM.  So, I guess it could come down to your infrastructure... what runs your servers, is it a cloud host, local machines?  And, is there a firewall or proxy?  And as a scientific test, have you tried a reference test (e.g. "superuser.com:443" or "google.com:443")?

Comment: @jehad no proxy, firewall has correct exceptions (AWS VPC), and SSL connection to all other servers works, even other servers in that domain

Comment: It's hard to say what to do next, since everything points to a problem in your specific environment;  if all public servers are reachable, but not this one, it really sounds like there must be a typo in your AWS security group.  Do you know how to tcpdump and wireshark? Reading Steffen Ullrich's responses below, he is correct in his analysis, and a tcpdump may help confirm.  Other basic experiments... 1)  try another VM/VPC (on your local laptop or in AWS), 2) May sound stupid, but forget curl, have you tried a basic ping ("ping powerschool.spokaneschools.org")?

Comment: @jehad ping works, also curl over http works. other vpc, or even classic ec2 (public. no vpc) do not work, but when works on ubuntu 12

Comment: @Kuf it seems you might not have your ca certificates installed. Have you tried running `apt-get install ca-certificates`? If something installs try connecting again.

Comment: @prateek61 yes, and I can connect over https to other servers in that domain, using the same wildecard certificates

Comment: See [curl use TLS instead of SSL](http://www.google.com/search?q=curl+use+tls+instead+of+ssl). But your situation might be the opposite since OS X uses OpenSSL 0.9.8 (i.e., connect with SSL instead of TLS). You should also ensure you are using [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). The `s_client` command is `openssl s_client -connect powerschool.spokaneschools.org:443 -tls1 -servername powerschool.spokaneschools.org`.

Comment: @jww thanks, I've tried that too w/o luck. Im really at loss here.. seems like it pin point to openssl, as ubuntu 12 on the same network worked..

Answer (score 2):

This works for me and it should work with your curl/openssl version too. errno 104 means a connection reset so I assume that some middlebox like a firewall is causing the problem. Check from another network where you can be sure that there are no firewalls involved.

Comment: I don't think this is a firewall issue - I can connect to the same server without SSL and I can connect to other servers in that domain, but not to that specific one. if it was a firewall issue I would expect all calls to that domain to fail.

Comment: @Kuf: this depends on the firewall. If it is a deep inspection firewall it will look at the connection target inside the TLS ClientHello message and block it if it does not like it. Since it works for me with the same version of openssl on same OS and the same target IP address and since the underlying TCP connection works but the server (or firewall) resets the connection it must be an issue in your network - or the server blocking you.

Comment: The server are in amazon VPC, and the only 'firewall' we use is the security groups, which allow all transport over port 443

Comment: @Kuf: "SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes" - looks like the reset happened before ClientHello was sent, so it is a block at the TCP level - either at your firewall or at some other firewall in front of the server.

Comment: Since it's working for you but not for me, is it safe to assume that the issue in on my server?

Comment: I launched a new ubuntu EC2 instance without any security settings and I get the same errors. once again, I can connect to other servers in that domain.

Comment: I started `12.04` ubuntu box, with exactly the same security settings, and I can connect to that server. Seems like it's related to AWS ubuntu release.

Comment: @Kuf: that's really strange. A packet capture might maybe help to debug this problem (upload to cloudshark.org).